# multi-page form with form:action

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is it possible to have a multi-page form with a custom form:action?
something like:

```
{exp:freeform:form 
    form_name="get_started" 
    form:id="get-started" 
    form:class="form-horizontal" 
    form:action="http:some-custom-url"
    multipage="yes" 
    multipage_page="{segment_2}"
}
```

If someone has a working example i would appreciate if he posted it here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Freeform operates of an Action ID  i. e. ?ACT=27 (that's an arbitrary number, yours may be different).

Second, Why do you need a custom form action?

If you need the form to finish on a new page, use the "return" parameter.

If you need to do some additional processing of the form data or some other action, Freeform has several extension hooks, enabling you to write an extension to do additional things.

Comment: I need it to send the form to my CRM instead of EE. That works well with single page forms, but when there are two or more the values from the previous page are not passed, so just the last page values are sent to the CRM..

Comment: You'll be well served here by writing an extension.  Then you should easily be able to gather all the form data and pass it to your CRM. Do you mind if I ask which one?

Comment: I've written the extension. 
CRM = Salesforce 
Automation plugin = Eloqua

Thanks for the reply! I didn't read it in time, but you were right... :-)